# Go from child navigation to parent navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have two `NavigationContainer`. What I want is when I am on the SignIn screen go to the MainPage. And the problem goes when I am in MainPage > Profile. The `Button` Logout does not go to the SignIn Screen.

App.js

```js
import React from "react";
import {SignIn} from './src/screen/authentication/signIn'
import {SignUp} from "./src/screen/authentication/signUp";
import {MainPage} from "./src/screen/drawer";
import {createStackNavigator} from "@react-navigation/stack";
import {NavigationContainer} from "@react-navigation/native";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <NavigationContainer>
                <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="SignIn" headerMode={null}>
                    <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignIn} />
                    <Stack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignUp} />
                    <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={MainPage} />
                </Stack.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
        );
    }
}
```

drawer.js

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createDrawerNavigator} from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import {Dashboard} from "./dashboard/dashboard";
import {AddWidget} from "./addWidget/addWidget";
import {Profile} from "./profile/profile";

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export function MainPage({navigation}) {
    return(
    <NavigationContainer independent={true}>
            <Drawer.Navigator>
                <Drawer.Screen name="Dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
                <Drawer.Screen name="Add widget" component={AddWidget} />
                <Drawer.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} initialParams={{navigation: () => navigation.navigate('SignIn')}} />
            </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
    );
}
```

Profile.js

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import {Button, Text, View} from "react-native";
import {useHistory} from "react-router-dom";
import {styles} from "./styles"

export function Profile({navigation}) {
    const history = useHistory();
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>Username</Text>
            <Button title="Logout" onPress={() => navigation.navigation} />
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: I think your ```onPress={() => navigation.navigation}``` might be wrong. first of all naming your initialParams or props navigation is a little confusing. try this though ```onPress={() => navigation.navigation()}``` and if that doesn't work try ```onPress={() => navigation()}``` I'm a little confused on how the params are being passed.

Comment: In both answers I have the same error: navigation is not a function is an instance of Object

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to just do this:

```
        <Button title="Logout" onPress={() => navigation.navigate("SignIn")} />
```

if the above doesn't work, you can try this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {Button, Text, View} from "react-native";
import {useHistory} from "react-router-dom";
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import {styles} from "./styles"

export function Profile() {
    const history = useHistory();
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>Username</Text>
            <Button title="Logout" onPress={() => navigation.navigate("SignIn")} />
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: I have this error `The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"SignIn"} was not handled by any navigator.`

Comment: <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignIn} /> this is still the name of your SignIn component right?

Comment: Yeah! But when I use `navigation` it in another `NavigationContainer` doesn't work. I don't if it is something wrong with the code

Comment: check my new edit. I don't doubt your own answer works, but it shouldn't be that complicated to navigate back to SignIn screen.

Answer (score 0):

A trick that I found is printing `props` with `console.log` and finding the function inside the object.

So what I did is changing the name of initialparams from Profile, navigation to parentNaivgation. And also removing ({navigation}) to (props) in the Profile component.

At the end, the route to finding the function navigation was `props.route.params.parentNavigation.navigate("SignIn")`